# Get traffic amount of LoadRunner transaction

Tags: loadrunner

Everyone.

Will be glad for any help. I need to find method of calculation of overall input/output traffic amount of an HP LoadRunner transaction .

For example we have:

```
lr_start_transaction("Test1");
web_url("www.ya.ru", ...... );
web_url("m.google.ru", ...... );
lr_end_transaction("Test1", LR_PASS);
```

So I need calculate amount of traffic(in bytes) of all requests to www.ya.ru and m.google.com.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't sure if it exactly what I'm need, but this partially work for me

up  = web_get_int_property(HTTP_INFO_TOTAL_REQUEST_STAT);
down  = web_get_int_property(HTTP_INFO_TOTAL_RESPONSE_STAT);

Sum of up and down - is required value.

Answer (score 1):

We do not use LoadRunner to test commercial websites.   This is a violation of both the license agreement, the ethics of the profession and a violation (in almost every case) against the user agreements for the public websites so targeted on the use of automated tools.

Just like we do not take a shotgun we received as a holiday gift and then aim randomly at items and property we do not own, control, manage or have written permission to shoot at.

Comment: Sorry? Can't understand why you mentioned this.

Comment: oh, ok! Got it ! :)

web_url("www.w3schools.com",...);

Comment: Yep, w3schools.com would also be a commercial site you don't shoot at without permission

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are on the right track with the web_get_int_property() function. This value accumulates from the first time you call it to the next time. The first time you use it in your code the value will be 0. The next time you use it add on all the previous web call sizes.

So, to use your original example it would look something liket this:

```
long request, response, total;

request = web_get_int_property(HTTP_INFO_TOTAL_REQUEST_STAT);
response = web_get_int_property(HTTP_INFO_TOTAL_RESPONSE_STAT);

lr_start_transaction("Test1");
web_url("www.ya.ru", ...... );
web_url("m.google.ru", ...... );
lr_end_transaction("Test1", LR_PASS);

request = web_get_int_property(HTTP_INFO_TOTAL_REQUEST_STAT);
response = web_get_int_property(HTTP_INFO_TOTAL_RESPONSE_STAT);

total = request + response;
```

The value of 'total' now contains the total size of all the requests and responses combined.